# Why does multiple calls to a tensor change its value each time using reshape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to debug some code using tensorflow inside a Jupyter notebook, and noticed a behavior I was not expecting. I noticed the output on all the print statements below produces a different output matrix for a_S. Why is that the case? I would have thought the a_S = tf.random... line would have been computed once. Then reshape runs. Since the reshape has happened already, the second and third calls would not change? Also, there is nothing in the line that causes a_S to change values unless it gets reassigned on each print somehow?

```
with tf.Session() as test:
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    a_S = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 7, 3], mean=1, stddev=4)
    a_G = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 7, 3], mean=1, stddev=4)
    J_style_layer = compute_layer_style_cost(a_S, a_G)

    m, n_H, n_W, n_C = a_G.get_shape().as_list()    

    #print("J_style_layer = " + str(J_style_layer.eval()))    
    print("J_style_layer2 = " + str(tf.reshape(a_S,[-1,n_C]).eval()))    
    print("J_style_layer3 = " + str(tf.reshape(a_S,[-1,n_C]).eval()))   
    print("J_style_layer3 = " + str(tf.reshape(a_S,[-1,n_C]).eval()))
```

Output:

````
J_style_layer2 = [[ -1.68344498e+00   1.89428568e+00   4.18909216e+00]
 [  1.38468242e+00   3.89259148e+00   2.35248661e+00]
 [ -1.92024541e+00   4.64613724e+00  -1.03752756e+00]
 [  4.89945602e+00  -7.53608036e+00   3.40916491e+00]
 [ -2.48588562e-01  -2.43247509e+00   8.14658546e+00]
 [ -1.76469064e+00   2.46943331e+00  -6.58598471e+00]
 [  7.14989901e-01   6.61043763e-01   4.19998550e+00]
 [  2.50623369e+00   4.50162363e+00   1.56363678e+00]
 [  3.42334247e+00  -8.45517635e+00   3.44382668e+00]
 [  1.22528923e+00   2.32022464e-01   1.46155047e+00]
 [  4.21129417e+00  -4.74298620e+00  -2.33842206e+00]
 [  1.37766552e+00  -3.39658976e+00   2.58650005e-01]
 [  1.25126350e+00   7.47679806e+00   5.12217665e+00]
 [  1.06175241e+01  -1.33930969e+00   9.90524054e-01]
 [ -5.41032219e+00  -5.45012522e+00  -1.77322006e+00]
 [ -4.09782457e+00   4.84395790e+00   2.74499822e+00]
 [ -9.30834293e-01   4.23307610e+00   5.83413506e+00]
 [ -2.86698842e+00  -5.36654806e+00   5.01119232e+00]
 [  2.98037910e+00   4.92405033e+00  -5.25441885e-01]
 [ -2.72941589e-03   6.32100248e+00   1.18444359e+00]
 [  2.83025682e-01  -4.18499231e+00   1.21345019e+00]
 [ -2.40400195e+00  -9.58013535e-01   7.72542524e+00]
 [  7.56009007e+00   5.49445009e+00   1.37617004e+00]
 [  5.44784927e+00   5.19741154e+00   4.22853470e+00]
 [  6.33485937e+00   1.05327117e+00   6.67146921e+00]
 [ -7.39221454e-01   3.46544337e+00  -1.65367699e+00]
 [  2.98967314e+00   1.79384637e+00  -1.96472073e+00]
 [  4.62664247e-01  -2.60094047e+00   4.77080643e-01]]

J_style_layer3 = [[ -0.96795654   3.94465876  -3.58533096]
 [  2.86657572   2.92028189   0.78808147]
 [  5.67818737   7.19356251   1.75864506]
 [ -2.02141023   0.41648489  -3.99681711]
 [  6.6851511   -4.29682779  -3.34400749]
 [  4.41373968  -0.86847067   5.63204002]
 [ -9.63679504   8.1419487    3.75494003]
 [ -0.99762154   2.573452     4.2510972 ]
 [ -1.79123497  -4.25948954   0.93429548]
 [ -3.26150131  -1.08424997  -2.17739081]
 [  5.18679285   5.10724735  -1.09539294]
 [  4.88294411  -3.20969486   8.78791428]
 [ -0.57771873  -2.99525881   2.32472777]
 [  1.36514819   2.2696619    2.3027463 ]
 [ -0.12692893   5.43655586   3.8288033 ]
 [  8.78754711   1.60508752  -0.90078032]
 [  0.03909284  -1.96740341   3.91209292]
 [ -2.23007846  -4.52376413   5.86214685]
 [ -2.71961284   1.87416935  10.11991024]
 [  2.14405489   1.23315167  -0.92923737]
 [ -4.21774721   1.86219811   0.18963808]
 [  5.43474102   4.82147026   0.60951805]
 [  5.42611742   1.51715541   4.34838676]
 [  1.46284723   6.85462999   3.54845214]
 [  5.46560287   2.08948946  -4.51927328]
 [  4.75431013   3.07936954   1.04333222]
 [  0.33259553  -0.8477515   -5.67703581]
 [ -0.64754236  -1.51528716   1.61516106]]

J_style_layer3 = [[  3.02279925   3.8460381   -3.10602283]
 [ -2.568856    -3.49679995   4.63807583]
 [  0.43675953   3.30313778  -8.33617496]
 [ -2.65553975   3.8253727    6.25587273]
 [  0.36330599   3.29871988   0.04714996]
 [  1.96590877  -1.24606895  -1.1522367 ]
 [  7.65323305  -2.6084044    0.94568378]
 [ -6.0451417    0.61521298  -3.07440042]
 [  4.33242702   1.00051153   1.34616411]
 [  3.1335001    1.86272466  10.08991051]
 [  0.5303157    0.73839551   7.40760946]
 [ -3.67107534   5.532269    -0.37785971]
 [ -0.60100091  -6.75784874   5.94953918]
 [  4.20541143  -1.72344565  -1.09141064]
 [ -5.15075636  -0.99294972   0.41196495]
 [ -2.43932915   2.13546133   1.18984747]
 [ -0.13836217   1.94724464   4.87366867]
 [ -2.72181702   3.02790046 -13.79762745]
 [ -1.3500247    3.25204515  -3.60114098]
 [  8.59435654  -0.15901434  -0.41931808]
 [  2.08263826  -1.55667186   3.37390661]
 [  2.86219215  -5.58194542  -9.734231  ]
 [  7.96397781   2.00432396  -6.02174616]
 [ -5.0965724    2.81370831  -0.9835161 ]
 [  1.61186719   4.38890743   6.93289137]
 [  4.34721375   0.67843139   4.64758778]
 [ -1.49379516   4.09007645   2.99832821]
 [ -2.06486607   2.20908523   3.9281044 ]]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
a_S = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 7, 3], mean=1, stddev=4)
```

what you are doing is creating a node in a graph, which tensorflow uses to do whatever computation you tell it to. In this case the node you create will **generate a random tensor**. This doesn't have anything to do with the reshape function. You have made a single node which when evalled will give you back a, new, random, tensor. You can see a minimal example as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf


with tf.Session() as test:
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    a_S = tf.random_normal([1])
    print("a " + str(a_S.eval()))
    print("b " + str(a_S.eval()))
```

which prints

```
a [-0.67086124]
b [0.9259123]
```

EDIT 
If you do something more complicated with it for example

```
import tensorflow as tf


with tf.Session() as test:
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    a_S = tf.random_normal([1])

    # print statement triggered whenever we go through node b_S
    a_S = tf.Print(a_S, [], message='We went through a_S', summarize=100)

    b_S = 2*a_S
    b_S = tf.Print(b_S, [], message='We went through b_S', summarize=100)

    a_S.eval()
    print('___________')
    b_S.eval()
    # We went through a_S
    # ___________
    # We went through a_S
    # We went through b_S
```

then TF will only run what it needs to evaluate what you ask for. The only things which evaulate some part of the graph are `.eval` and `session.run(..)`. Everything else is adding things to the graph, either tensors or operations.

Comment: For clarity and to help understanding, lets assume a_S is part of a larger graph. Say a few nodes have already been computed and a_S does a little more than just spit out a random number (say it multiplies the input by 2). There are also nodes after a_S. Would it be safe to say, a_S.eval() would run all the graph before and including a_S, but not anything after a_S? Then each call runs the graph independently. I am still working on getting my head around graphs and how they work in the larger scope. Maybe as an aside, how do you tell which tf methods (like reshape) compute things vs add a node